# Unable to Remove User Profile Application Pool

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, service-application, application-pool

`Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | Format-List`

After running the above commandlet, I get that the `User Profile Application Pool` is present and online.

But, when I run the following commandlet, I get an error.

```
Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool -Identity "User Profile Application Pool"
```

The error is as below -

```
Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:3 char:1
+ Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool -Identity "User Profile Application P ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData:     (Microsoft.Share...ApplicationPool:SPCmdletRemoveI...ApplicationPool) [Remove-    SPServiceAp 
   plicationPool], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :         Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRemoveIisWebServiceApplicationPool
```

Any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: why u want to remove the upa pool? did you remove the UPA completely or another pool running the UPA?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the unique ID (GUID) for the Application Pool Instead. You can get the ID from (Get-SPServiceApplicationPool).Id. You won't see Service APp Pool Names in IIS just the GUID associated with the app pool.

Comment: It was not in IIS as well. I tried finding via GUID as well but couldn't. Ultimately, a Windows reboot fixed the problem :|

Answer (score 0):

Chek the below points:

- Make sure that the application pool does not contain any application. where you can't delete any application pool contains the application.

  - Open IIS > Application pools > check the number of applications in application column > Make sure the applications count is 0.
- Make sure the Application Pool Name is typed correctly as listed in `Get-SPServiceApplicationPool`.

Comment: I checked each and every application inside every application pool in IIS but I could not find this Application with it's Identity.

Regarding the name being correct, it is correct. Just checked it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed after rebooting the machine and then I was then able to create the User Profile Service Application.